# Are ergonomics questions regarding home offices off-topic?

Tags: discussion, offtopic

[Would a huge screen/projector be healthier for the eyes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/148267/would-a-huge-screen-projector-be-healthier-for-the-eyes)

As of the time of writing this meta post, the question above has 4 close votes.

Ergonomics questions in general are on topic but someone questioned whether it being about a home office made this specific question off-topic. (Two close votes for Too Broad and two close votes stating the question belongs on another site.)

Are ergonomics questions only valid for business offices? I'm interested in the general case.

Also, some additional guidance to the ergonomics tag would be useful either way.

Comment: They are absolutely on topic.  But this stack is notoriously close-happy.

Comment: I think part of the confusion was that the OP did not lead with the emphasis on ergonomics of the home office I edited it to make it the focus of the question

Comment: Question seemed valid to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> someone questioned whether it being about a home office made this specific question off-topic

Do we no longer take questions from professional green keepers because the don't do their job indoors at a desk? What about pilots, they sure don't see an office in a while. And I guess Fisherman are out, too? No.

It's a workplace when work is performed there. If the question is about the setup used for work, then it's on-topic. We have no rules that this has to happen in a fixed, employer-owned building.

Comment: agreed.  The close happy crew is getting annoying.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's feedback. I'm marking this one as the answer because I think your point about a workplace not even having to be an office would be most convincing to someone who thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth I didn't VTC that question (and it's still just about clinging to being open at time of writing).

I think ergonomics questions pertaining to home-offices *can* be on-topic here, I'm really on the fence with this particular question though; it's certainly a little out-of-the-norm but that doesn't make something off-topic. Given the unusual setup I doubt most people versed in workplace (including home workplace) ergonomics would know the answer but a question being difficult to answer doesn't make it off-topic either.

The OP *might* stand a better chance of getting useful info on Medical Sciences - but it would have to be framed very specifically as a question discussing display use under such circumstances in the general case. For very good reasons Med Sci doesn't allow questions that have the slightest whiff of being something that might be considered "Personal medical advice".

I think Kilisi made a good effort at an answer - and the OP certainly seemed happy enough to accept that.

Comment: I edited it to make the focus more on the business/workplace aspect.  Like Joe, I think we close far to many questions, and I've stopped voting to close.

Comment: I feel that it is on topic and should not be closed, and @RichardSaysReinstateMonica your clarifying edit will hopefully make that clear to others as well. It is one vote away from closing, so unfortunately, we are on the brink of needing to VTRO.

Answer (score 5):

If the ergonomics question would apply to the work office, it would equally apply to the home office.

We have some folks who like to close as many questions as possible.

If this question gets closed, I'll vote to re-open.